# Excell working with dates

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a prediction of income, at the moment I have a basic spreadsheet. there are 2 variables that change constantly and whenever I change them the whole spreadsheet changes and I don't want the past days to change.

My spreadsheet:

**Date** 24oct 25oct 26oct

**income** 300  250   500

income is x*y

variables x and y

if I change any of the variables it changes the whole days and I don't that to happen, today is 25oct it should change this day and 26oct and not 24oct.

This is a simple example ofcourse the real spreadsheet is not like this but I think it's enough to see what I'm looking for.

Comment: Your question is not clear, you need to take a little bit more effort to explain the problem clearly if you really want an answer

Comment: Maybe now is a bit more explicit, sorry

Comment: Sounds like you need an X and a Y for each day that way when you change it for one day, it will not affect the other days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, you want to store the values of the income associated with any time before (and including) today. This can be accomplished by copying the values into the cells, and protecting them from edits.

The following code checks the range of dates for anything less than or equal to today. If it is either today or a previous day, it copies only values of the date and the income, and protects the cells from edits.

```
Sub UpdateProtection()

'Declare the range of dates
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("A1:A4") 'Or whatever your range of dates is

'Set the time as the current time
MyTime = Date

'Loop through each cell in the range of dates
For Each Cell In Rng
    'If the date in the cell is less or equal to now, lock the cells
    If Cell.Value <= MyTime Then
        Cell.Formula = Cell.Text        'Copy the Date
        Cell.Locked = True              'Lock the Cell
        'Copy the value of the "Income"
        Cell.Offset(1, 0).Formula = Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
        'Lock the associated income
        Cell.Offset(1, 0).Locked = True
    Else
        'Unlock the date if it's after today
        Cell.Locked = False
        'Unlock the associated "Income"
        Cell.Offset(1, 0).Locked = False
    End If
Next Cell

'Protect the sheet
Sheets("MySheetName").Protect

End Sub
```

This assumes that the incomes are just below the dates. You could call this sub from a `Worksheet_Change` event, if you wanted it to update the protection every time the sheet was updated.

If I've misunderstood the question, or missed anything let me know.

Comment: So for what I understood, I have to use the code everyday? or does it start when i open the file or update it? Cell.Offset(1,0) means the one under the date cell, meaning the (2,0) would be 2 cells below?

Thank you for the answer

Comment: You _could_ run it every day. Or you could set it to run when you open the workbook (much more better). This is done using workbook_open. More on that can be found here: [link] (http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/08/18/running-macros-when-a-workbook-is-opened/). And yes, the 1 in the cell.offset(1,0) refers to the rows below the cell. Cell.offset(2,0) would offset from cell by 2 rows.

Comment: Haven't tested yet, but another question came through my mind, MyTime = Date. do I have to submit the current date or does it automaticly fetch the current date?

Comment: Sure thing! `Date` in VBA is equivalent to `Now` in vanilla Excel. It will return the current date. Thanks for accepting the answer, by the way. Happy Excel-ing!